# Funções em Python

Tags: python, funções

Fiz esse exercício de Python, versão 2.7:

> #### Instruções
>
> Primeiro, defina (def) uma função chamada cube (cubo) que
>   toma um argumento chamado number (número). Não se esqueça dos
>   parênteses e dos dois pontos!
>
> Faça essa função retornar (return) o cubo daquele número (ou seja,
>   aquele número multiplicado por si mesmo, e depois multiplicado mais
>   uma vez por si mesmo).
>
> Defina uma segunda função chamada by_three que
>   toma um argumento chamado number.
>
> Se (if) esse número for divisível por 3, by_three deve chamar
>   cube(number) e retornar seu resultado. Caso contrário, by_three deve
>   retornar falso (return False).
>
> Não se esqueça que as declarações if e else precisam de um : ao final
>   daquela linha!

Aqui meu código:

```
def cube(number):
    return number * number * number #number elevado ao cubo(3)

def by_three(number):
    if(number % 3 ==0):
        cube(number)
        print "resultado = %d" % number
    else:
        print "number nao e divisivel por 3"
        return False
```

Mas quando executo ele mostra isso:

> Oops, tente outra vez. Sua funcao by_three retorna None com a entrada 3 quando deveria retornar 27. by_three deveria retornar cube(n) se n for divisivel por 3.

Comment: Acho que está faltando código aí, não?

Comment: Creio que não...

Comment: Eu havia lido "Quando **executo**, ele mostra isso", agora que eu li corretamente, percebi que eu não entendi qual é a sua dúvida. Poderia dizer qual que é?

Comment: O código tem uma função que chama outra função(elevado number ao cubo) se ela for divisível por 3, ela mostra o resultado. mas esta dando erro.

Comment: testei no pythonfiddle e deu certo sua função, não deu nenhum erro 
 http://pythonfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema está nas linhas:

```
    cube(number)
    print "resultado = %d" % number
```

Que você chama a função `cube()` passando o `number`, mas você se esquece de fazer sua função `by_three()` retorne algo, como ele não entra no `else` o código da função roda até o final sem encontrar nenhum `return`, e por isso o retorno acaba sendo `None`.

Já o retorno da função `cube()` é simplesmente perdido. Você deveria retornar o resultado da função `cube()`, assim:

```
    return cube(number)
```

Seu código poderia ficar assim por exemplo:

```
def cube(number):
    return number * number * number  # number elevado ao cubo(3)


def by_three(number):
    if(number % 3 == 0):
        print "resultado = %d" % cube(number)
        return cube(number)
    else:
        print "number nao e divisivel por 3"
        return False

print by_three(3)
```

Comment: Ele continua mostrando isso: Oops, tente outra vez. Sua funcao by_three retorna None com a entrada 3 quando deveria retornar 27. by_three deveria retornar cube(n) se n for divisivel por 3.

Comment: Ah, é só por um return no lugar do print então

Comment: Posso printar algo com o return?

Comment: Você pode printar **e** retornar, caso seja do seu interesse

Comment: ok, muito obrigado!!